# OSX/BASH: Can access defaults in terminal, but not script

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sh

I'm writing what should be a basic BASH script, but I've run into some trouble.

Running

```
defaults read org.eyebeam.SelfControl
```

in a terminal returns all of the defaults associated with SelfControl:

```
  {
    BlockDuration = 6;
    BlockLengthInterval = 15;
    BlockSoundShouldPlay = 1;
    BlockStartedDate = "4001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000";
    GetStartedShown = 1;
    HostBlacklist =     (
        "*:80",
        "*:443"
    );
    "MASPreferences Selected Identifier View" = GeneralPreferences;
    MaxBlockLength = 7200;
    SUHasLaunchedBefore = 1;
    SULastCheckTime = "2017-05-07 05:09:59 +0000";
    VerifyInternetConnection = 0;
    WhitelistAlertSuppress = 1;
}
```

**However**, running that same exact line of code in a bash script returns only one thing -- BlockDuration, which I edit using

`defaults write org.eyebeam.SelfControl BlockDuration -int 6`

in the script. Specifically, I do not want to edit `BlockStartedDate`, but I want to pull its value. Does anyone have an idea of why I can in the terminal, but not in my script?

Comment: How is the script being run? If you're using `sudo`, launchd, cron, or something, then perhaps the script is being run as a different user. Defaults are typically per-user, so one user would not see the defaults of another user account. If that doesn't explain it, then show the script you're running and the command you're using to run it.

Comment: Double whammy -- It's running in the root crontab. How could I point it to my own defaults?

Comment: Well, why is it running in the root crontab? I mean, I could suggest that you `su` to your user account, but why not just run it in your user account's crontab to begin with?

Comment: The operation I want to run requires superuser access

Comment: I think it should work to do `sudo -s YourUserAccountName defaults read org.eyebeam.SelfControl BlockStartedDate`.

Comment: Not quite -- it turns out it the magic trick is `sudo -u`, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Oops. Yeah, I meant `-u`. Sorry.